# Determine if Set of Polygons can make a Polyhedron

Tags: geometry

Given a set of polygons, how does one determine if the set, or one of its subsets, can describe all the faces of any polyhedron? Is there a general algorithm that can scale to determine if a set of n-1 dimensional polytopes can describe all the faces of any n dimensional polytope?

Comment: Are you also given their positions or is "some assembly required"?

Comment: @Misha Lavrov No position information is given. We must decide if the construction of _any_ polyhedron is possible with the given faces.

Comment: Your question needs first to be settled in 3D before any general attempt in nD ; moreover, what do you mean by "scale to determine" ? You should take an example of which kind of "input" we give to your intended algorithm which is supposed to answer : "Yes, it is possible, or no". A certain number of squares, triangles, etc... but how for example are their sides ? Given or not given ?